# Cant install Ubuntu. How do you format a Windows HDD

Tags: format

I have an HP 630, and would like to install Ubuntu.

All goes well until the point where you have to choose how you want Ubuntu installed. I choose on the whole HDD, I want Windows off the HDD.

I press enter and about 5 seconds later the CD tray open and the computer reboots. This happens over and over.

How do I format this Window HDD completely to install Ubuntu 13.04.

I have tried 3 different CD's and the same thing happens each time.

Comment: Your computer should not unexpectedly reboot at that point. I think this is a bug of the installer. I also think I've seen a similar question here in the last few days.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04 and the same happens with all of these CD's.

Comment: /home/ubuntu/Pictures/Screenshot from 2013-06-26 16:01:44.png

Comment: I do not if I have done this right. Hope you can see this snaphot.

Comment: @heldeman: Just below your question and above the comments, click `edit` to edit your question. There should be a button that reads `img` (to the left of the enumerated list button), click it and upload your screenshot.

Comment: It may be useful to others if you answer your own question with as much detail as possible about how your friend formatted the HDD and solved the problem and accept that answer as the correct one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want windows, then when you get to the installation type screen, just choose Erase disk and install Ubuntu.  If you want more control on size of partition and swap, then choose Something else, which will let you do manual partitioning.

[image]

Comment: I think the question clearly states that he is already doing this, but that after clicking the "Install Now" button the system unexpectedly reboots without installing. Am I correct here, @heldeman?

Comment: I think the question clearly states that he is already doing this, but that after clicking the "Install Now" button the system unexpectedly reboots without installing. Am I correct here, @heldeman? – gertvdijk. You are right but i am so lucky a friend came around formatted the drive and installed Ubuntu. I must say you blokes are great. Thanks

Comment: @heldeman, please don't mark an answer to be correct with **green check** if it does not solve the problem. This will be misleading to others with similar issues. Mitch, consider removing the answer, based on heldman's comment above.

Comment: @gertvdijk The OP didn't say which option he choose, that's why I included both options.

Comment: @user68186 The OP didn't say which option he choose, that's why I included both options.

Comment: How did your friend format the hard drive?

Comment: I don't know why everybody rushes with the down-vote, before knowing all the facts.  His friend could have used the something else option.

Comment: Mitch, OP said in the question **"I choose on the whole HDD"** (sic). The question was not about which option to choose. It was about the unexpected reboot. Your answer does not address this issue at all. If you edit your answer, I will withdraw the down-vote.

Comment: @user68186 I would want to know what did his friend do, because I feel that there is something we don't know.

Comment: Fair enough Mitch. It is very odd that the Live system would reboot before install. The problem may be with the original partition table/ format resulting in an exception at the format stage it and caused the reboot. If so, your question, on how the friend formatted the HDD is very pertinent.

Comment: @user68186 I've been doing this for over 30 years, and I've seen my share of weird :)